# how do I limit the number of open torrents in transmission?

Tags: transmission

I want to limit the number of torrents that are simultaneously being downloaded in Transmission. I could find any such option in transmission preferences. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**First, add the PPA and update if you haven't already (Close transmission first):**
Command line way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk transmission-common
```

**Or:**

1. Open Update Manager.
2. Click "Settings".
3. Click "Other Sources".
4. Click "Add".
5. Enter (change oneiric to your version if different):

   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
6. Close Settings Window.
7. Click "Check".
8. Once complete, click "Install Updates".

**Second, Edit the Preferences in Transmission:**
 1. Open Transmission.
 2. Open "Edit" ➜ "Prefernces".
 3. Under the "Downloading" Tab, Under "Queue", set "Maximum Active Downloads" to the limit you desire.

[image: Transmission Preferences]

Comment: I dont have downloading tab in Preferences window :(

Comment: Did you install the PPA and updates? Ubuntu won't recognise the update unless you add the PPA.

Comment: yes I did add ppa. After that I updated and then installed the two packages but I still dont have that downloading tab.

Comment: Check for updates using the Update Manager, there is a chance i got the package names wrong, or didn't list all of them.

Comment: no luck. I looked for packages with transmission in their names but couldnt find any package that could solve the issue. I even tried installing transmission-qt but that didnt help either.

Comment: Go to Help -> About. Check you are on Version 2.41 If not install https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/ppa/+files/transmission_2.41-0ubuntu0.11.10.0_all.deb which will just put everything to the most recent version run sudo dpkg -i transmission_2.41-0ubuntu0.11.10.0_all.deb to install in terminal or open in the software center.

Comment: I run ubuntu 10.04 and I have Transmission 2.33. That deb for 2.41 wont install because of unmet dependencies.

Comment: If it lists the dependencies, try installing them. if not, or if that doesn't work try https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/ppa/+files/transmission-gtk_2.41-0ubuntu0.11.10.0_i386.deb and https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/ppa/+files/transmission-common_2.41-0ubuntu0.11.10.0_all.deb

Comment: no mate. the package transmission-gtk depends on appindicator1 and I dont think that I can use that package of 11.10 because of changes in Desktop environment and all.

Comment: In 11.10? That's what i'm using too. Because Transmission is default software, it's appindicator is whitelisted (i think). It's working for me in Unity.

Comment: I am using 10.04

Comment: In that case the latest version (with the feature you're after) might only be for 11.10. I would try installing it, i'm pretty sure you can, just the appindicator won't show up in 11.04

Answer (score 0):

For others unable to find the above, maximize Transmission and hover over title bar to find Edit --> Preferences --> Downloading tab

You could have just missed *maximizing* Transmission.